# How to take a snapshot of Chrome's cookies and caches?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, snapshot

I want to save a snapshot of chrome's cache and cookies for when I need to use it later, But cannot find a elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, there's probably no "elegant" way to do this at all; you could try to copy the user's profile folder (e.g. `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1`) somewhere and restore it later, but this seems likely to cause at least some problems upon restoring it.

Notably, you probably want more than just the cache and cookies-- you'll probably want HTML5 localStorage, indexedDB, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. For my scenario is: We are developing a React web app, When we release a new version, page may crashed by cache data(majority of LocalStorage) incompatible,  Because of developer have not considered this situation. And this issue are difficult to finds in testing environment. For now time, I'm trying to solution this problem by `Docker commit`, But i think is not a graceful way.